# Sort CSV data with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV that have this example format (there will be many rows like this format):

```
1131,01/06/15,PROFI ROM FOOD SRL,290.7,,

1131,,,,,

3811861,01/12/15,CENTRUL TERITORIAL DE CALCUL,141.36,,

3811861,,ELECTRONIC SA,,,

49171,01/15/15,AUTOGLOBUS 2000 SRL,"1,138.10",,

49171,,,,,

2024194PJ,01/08/15,SOCIETATEA NATIONALA DE,"2,088.17",,

2024194PJ,,RADIOCOMUNICATII SA,,,
```

My desired output after the sort should by like this :

```
1131,01/06/15,PROFI ROM FOOD SRL,290.7,,

3811861,01/12/15,CENTRUL TERITORIAL DE CALCUL ELECTRONIC SA,141.36,,

49171,01/15/15,AUTOGLOBUS 2000 SRL,"1,138.10",,

2024194PJ,01/08/15,SOCIETATEA NATIONALA DE RADIOCOMUNICATII SA,"2,088.17",,
```

When script is detecting a row with a number and nothing after that like this (1131,,,,,) it should delete that row, when he detects a number 2 spaces(can be more than 2 sometime, but usually 2) like this (3811861,,ELECTRONIC SA,,,) he should get that string (ELECTRONIC SA) and append it to above row at index 2 like this (CENTRUL TERITORIAL DE CALCUL ELECTRONIC SA).

What I'm thinking is that I should make a list of lists for each row, do a for loop and append what I need (maybe a regex sort?) and ignore the rows that I don't need, but I don't know how exactly is the best way to do it? Can anyone help with a easy script, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Try to write code on your own. We will help you with errors but we will not write complete code for you.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to load the csv data, and then just loop through the lines and filter out the ones you want.